# Build is Success but Test does not run with Maven

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm Unable to run My test using Maven, on Clean Install from goals, .Pom and .Jar files are created to the .m2 folder, but the test is not running, can someone please help TIA.

1. TestNG File

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="Project_Pkg_Mvn.NewTest1" />
    </classes>
  </test>
  <!-- Test -->
</suite>
<!-- Suite -->
```

2. Pom.xml

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       4.0.0
       Project_Maven_Group_Test
       Project_Maven_Artifact_Test
       0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

   ```
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   </properties>


   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
           <version>3.14.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
           <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
           <version>6.14.3</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
           <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
           <version>2.6</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.2</version>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.5.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <fork>true</fork>
                   <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe</executable>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.22.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <suiteXmlfiles>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlfiles>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.22.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <suiteXmlFiles>
                       <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                   </suiteXmlFiles>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

   Console Output

   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
   [WARNING] 
   [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for Project_Maven_Group_Test:Project_Maven_Artifact_Test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin @ line 50, column 12
   [WARNING] 
   [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
   [WARNING] 
   [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
   [WARNING] 
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --------< Project_Maven_Group_Test:Project_Maven_Artifact_Test >--------
   [INFO] Building Project_Maven_Artifact_Test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
   [WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Project_Maven_Artifact_Test ---
   [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
   [INFO] Copying 0 resource
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Project_Maven_Artifact_Test ---
   [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Project_Maven_Artifact_Test ---
   [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
   [INFO] Copying 1 resource
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Project_Maven_Artifact_Test ---
   [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ Project_Maven_Artifact_Test ---
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 1.701 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-10T21:58:30+05:30
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with your pom. Just make sure that the path for you testng.xml is right

```
<suiteXmlfiles>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlfiles>
```

One way to do this just place your testng.xml into your root folder where pom file is located and then change pom to:

```
<suiteXmlfiles>testng.xml</suiteXmlfiles>
```

Rerun and see!

Comment: does your testng run fine without using maven command line? When you do RunAs TestNGsuite ?

Comment: can you also tell me the exact command you enter when you run the test?

Comment: Yes, my TestNg suite runs fine, and the Command to execute is "mvn clean install" from Command Prompt. Also, I have run directly POM from eclipse, but of no help, it just creates a JAR file and finishes the execution.

Comment: Added the Updated POM and tried running it, but of no luck.

Answer (score 0):

ok can you replace you pom from properties to the end with this pom file (there are some extra dependecies in it that you dont need ) I just want to see if the surefire and the jdk can fix the problem )

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Below plug-in is used to execute tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aeonbits.owner</groupId>
        <artifactId>owner</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>       
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>        
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```