# Aeonbits.OWNER doesn't work in maven? Troubleshooting

Tags: java, maven, owner

For some reason when I run **mvn clean test -Denv=test -Dplatform=test** maven cannot execute owner's method

```
private static Environment config = configFactory.create(Environment.class, System.getProperties());

private static String url = config.getUrl();
```

It just returns nulls instead of fields in **.property** file

I have several **.property** files like this:
**prod.desktop.properties**
And get their fields with:

```
@Config.Sources({"classpath:${env}.${platform}.properties"})
```

I think [Build is Success but Test does not run with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745060/build-is-success-but-test-does-not-run-with-maven) have almost the same problem.
Building works fine and program runs until the certain moment where var supposed to return a property. 
If instead of, for example, **env = config.getEnv()** I'll use **env = System.getProperty('env')** then everything is good.

[Full pom.xml](https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cbadcec2)

If I run project via IDEA runner (TestNG config) - everything works 100% fine. I have no idea why mvn builder doesn't want to execute ConfigFactory.create() at some point and can't find anyone who have ran **maven+owner**.

Additional info:
If I run config method above but specify **-Durl={url}** as arg then instead of getting url from the property of Environment.class url be as it's in -Durl. So smh method works but for some reason cannot reach Environment.class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'v localized the problem.

For some reason mvn cannot read property file adressed like this:

```
@Config.Sources({"classpath:${property}.properties"})
```

So instead you have to change it to:

```
@Config.Sources({"file:src/main/resources/${property}.properties"})
```